# Issue with XML / SelectNodes using ASP VBScript

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

Got an issue displaying information from XML. I think it has something to do with selecting the correct node (Company Name). Need a fresh opinion... got a feeling I am probably overlooking something really simple. Code as follows.

XML

```xml
<GovTalkMessage>
    <EnvelopeVersion>1.0</EnvelopeVersion>
    <Header>
        <MessageDetails>
            <Class>CompanyDetails</Class>
            <Qualifier>response</Qualifier>
            <TransactionID>9999999999999</TransactionID>
            <GatewayTest>TRUE</GatewayTest>
            <GatewayTimestamp>2013-09-24T17:51:41-00:00</GatewayTimestamp>
        </MessageDetails>
        <SenderDetails>
            <IDAuthentication>
                <SenderID>******</SenderID>
                <Authentication>
                    <Method>CHMD5</Method>
                    <Value></Value>
                </Authentication>
            </IDAuthentication>
            <EmailAddress>rte@rrfsolicitors.com</EmailAddress>
        </SenderDetails>
    </Header>
    <GovTalkDetails>
        <Keys/>
    </GovTalkDetails>
    <Body>
        <CompanyDetails>
            <CompanyName>MILLENNIUM STADIUM PLC</CompanyName>
            <CompanyNumber>03176906</CompanyNumber>
            <RegAddress>
                <AddressLine>MILLENNIUM STADIUM</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine>WESTGATE STREET</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine>CARDIFF</AddressLine>
                <AddressLine>CF10 1NS</AddressLine>
            </RegAddress>
        </CompanyDetails>
    </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

ASP code:

```vb
Set XMLDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
XMLDom.Async = False
XMLDom.LoadXML (theXML)

theNode = "/GovTalkMessage/Body/CompanyDetails"

Set NodeList = XMLDom.SelectNodes(theNode)
nodeCount = XMLDom.SelectNodes(theNode).Length
If XMLDom.ParseError = 0 Then
    Response.Write(nodeCount)
    For Each Node in NodeList 
        response.Write(Node.Text & "<br>")
    Next
Else
    response.Write("Error Parsing Results")
End If
Set XMLDom = Nothing
```

Results:
nodeCount = 0

Comment: Your code produced a node count of 1 when I tested it with the XML you provided. Is the above the actual complete XML you're processing or is there more to it? Also, your description doesn't match your code. You said you want to select `<CompanyName>` nodes, but your code selects `<CompanyDetails>` nodes.

Comment: Ansgar Wiecher you are correct thank you.. Should of tried that initially myself. Its working on the posted XML. I did strip out a few attributes in the hope it would make my question easier to under stand. I have the full XML code here; http://jsfiddle.net/dannyj6/UqTqa/

Comment: Please use a pastebin that doesn't require JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry Ansgar... http://pastebin.com/xCUVNjRn. Thank you

Comment: @DolphinDan, please edit the full XML back into the original question. Not everyone who looks at this question will bother reading the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XML file uses namespaces. The node

```
<CompanyDetails xmlns="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema
     http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/CompanyDetails-v2-1.xsd">
```

defines a default namespace `http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema`. Unless a node is using an explicit namespace (e.g. `<xsi:Something>`) that default namespace is used, and you must define and use that default namespace in your code as well. Something like this should work:

```vb
uri = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema"
XMLDom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='" & uri & "'"

theNode = "//ns:CompanyDetails"
Set NodeList = XMLDom.SelectNodes(theNode)
nodeCount = NodeList.Length

WScript.Echo nodeCount
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the node `CompanyName`, then try this:

```
theNode = "/GovTalkMessage/Body/CompanyDetails/CompanyName"
Response.Write (XMLDom.SelectSingleNode(theNode).xml)
```

Comment: `.xml` will produce value *and* tags of the node. He most likely wants just the value, so `.text` would be more appropriate. Also, you [shouldn't use parentheses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) around the argument of the `Write` method.