# How can I access the following XML element or remove the namespace with VBScript?

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am trying to access an XML element via VBScript and it's not working, probably because of the namespace. I've tried so many different ways but I always get the error "VBScript Runtime Error: Object Required"

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AssetInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://unitedwholesale.com.au/webservices/external/">
  <ID>66399</ID>
  <AssetLife>3.00</AssetLife>
  <BookValue>0.00</BookValue>
  <Tag>IT12345</Tag>
</AssetInfo>
```

VBScript:

```
Dim ns
ns = "http://unitedwholesale.com.au/webservices/external/"
oXMLFile.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns='" & ns & "'"
Set oNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/xmlns:AssetInfo/xmlns:Tag").Text
If Not oNode Is Nothing Then
  Response.Write oNode
Else
  Response.Write oXMLFile.xml
End If
```

I've also tried:

```
Set oNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("//AssetInfo/Tag").Text
```

and

```
Set oNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/ns:AssetInfo/ns:Tag").Text
```

...all to no avail!

I'd be quite happy just to ditch all the namespace if that would be easiest.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with XML / SelectNodes using ASP VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987954/issue-with-xml-selectnodes-using-asp-vbscript). Basically you need to define a symbolic name for the namespace (`"xmlns` **`:ns`** `='" & ns & "'"`) and then use that symbolic name in your XPath expression (`//ns:AssetInfo`).

Comment: Just as a side remark, did you use `oxmlFile.setProperty SelectionLanguage", "XPath"`? Further: your `oNode` does not really contain a node object, but just a text string. First use `Set oNode = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("/xmlns:AssetInfo/xmlns:Tag")` and if the node is not nothing, extract the text using `txt = oNode.Text`. Note: I do not claim this will solve your issue, see the comment of @AnsgarWiechers for that. These are just additional issues I spotted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ansgar Wiechers! You pointed me in the right direction. I redefined the ns variable with the symbolic name and used that and it works!

```
' Configure the namespace
Dim ns
ns = "http://unitedwholesale.com.au/webservices/external/"
oXML.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns ='" & ns & "'"

WScript.Echo oXML.SelectSingleNode("/ns:AssetInfo/ns:Tag").Text
```

Correct output!

Thanks very much