# Classic ASP xmlDOM not turning any result?

Tags: asp-classic, wikipedia-api, xmldom

This code dont respond any result. I dont know why? Can you help me?

```
<%
    Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDOM.async = False
    xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
    xmlDOM.Load("https://tr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&maxage=600&smaxage=1200&action=opensearch&search=fizik&limit=10")
    Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("Item")
    For Each itemAttrib In itemList
        newsDate    =   itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("Description").text
%>
<%=newsDate%>
<%
    Next
    Set xmlDOM = Nothing
    Set itemList = Nothing
%>
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987954/issue-with-xml-selectnodes-using-asp-vbscript .

Comment: You might want to post the xml your query returns. Also XML is not recommended any more for mediawiki api. You might want to use Json instead.