# Use VBScript to Parse a Webpage's Text

Tags: parsing, vbscript, html

I'm currently working on a VBScript that will open multiple URLs in order to update documents on a server. I was wondering if there was a way to parse a webpage's content for a specific string, in this case being the updateResult SUCCESS line shown below:

[image]

I need to be able to record the success of this webpage text as opposed to the failure page below:

[image]

This is all that is on the webpage. How would I go about parsing the text of both these types of pages in order to know that the document has updated correctly or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading XML file from httprequest output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339797/loading-xml-file-from-httprequest-output)

Comment: Did you check the [`responseXML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066.aspx) property? Beware that the XML uses [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039218/1630171).